# Rollback changes in the detail table

Tags: yii2

How can I rollback changes made in a detail table (edit, delete in a gridview) to it's original state, when the user does not click the save button in the master table.

Answer (score 0):

What changes are there to rollback? You should not be making any changes until they press the same button.

1. Load the activeDataProvider data in an array and put it in the session.
2. Use the session array to load data in an ArrayDataProvider
3. show the data using the GridView. Any changes to the gridview should be done on the array (not the db)
4. when the user saves the master record apply the changes from the array to the DB.

You should also not be making any changes to the DB directly because of concurrent users.

Comment: Thanks Mihia for your comment on this.

Comment: I used the Session array and the ArrayDataProvider for this now now. Problem is solved.